# Why does AngularJS date validation fail if year.length < 3; How to Fix?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, date

I've got a simple date input. I want to make sure a date of birth is less than a certain age and more than a certain age, and that the field is required. So, we're using three Angular validators, seemingly exactly according to spec. It generally works: here's a working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/xmlilley/pen/ZGZYXm) showing the approach, and the results (using ng-messages).

(Note that we're using a stock HTML5 `date` input, with no additional features.)

The trick is something one of my testers discovered: the date range validation works well... unless you try entering a date with *fewer than 3 digits in the year*. So, if you enter '2000' as the year, you fail validation for being too young. If you enter '200', you fail validation for being too old. Everything works as expected. But if you just enter '20' or '2' as the year (which is a legitimate - if uncommon - year to be entering), suddenly you pass validation, the form submits... and everything breaks.

Here's the input's HTML:

```
<input ng-model="demoData.dob" name="dob" type="date" min="{{minDobString}}"
 max="{{maxDobString}}" required />
```

FWIW, the date validation strings are Angular/ISO spec, which we're calculating in the controller:

```
var yearMS = 365 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); // 365 days
var now = new Date().getTime();
var maxDobMS = now - (18 * yearMS);
var minDobMS = now - (122.5 * yearMS);
var maxDobString = new Date(maxDobMS).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
var minDobString = new Date(minDobMS).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

I *think* that this is a bug in Angular's validator/pipeline. At a minimum, if a date isn't formatted properly enough to count as a working `date` type, it should fail the `required` validation. If not that, it should fail the `min` or `max` validation. (Since any date in the year 0020 AD is far too ancient.) But they shouldn't all pass.

Question #1: Is there something I've got mis-configured and can fix easily?

Question #2: Does anyone know a simple workaround (short of writing a custom validator to replace what's broken in Angular)?

Question #3: if (!#1 && !#2), any other insight I should include in filing a bug report?

Comment: I don't see any problem. http://jsfiddle.net/cL3jkmwj/

Comment: to be honest, I think it's perfectly okay to not allow 2-digit years. Either way, you might want to specifically add `if` statements for year length to handle it

Comment: @casraf Right, but Angular *is* allowing the 2-digit years, by failing to process 2-digit years as a validation failure. Validation simply breaks and stops working when it encounters them. Please check the CodePen to see what happens. Validation works perfectly for the 3+ digit years, then disappears completely on anything shorter.

Comment: @HeiN - Do you mean you feel that Angular is working as it should, or that you don't see any problem in my code that would cause the unexpected behavior? (In your fiddle, the validation error that displays properly with short years is the browser-native message. Unfortunately, that doesn't do a thing to ensure full validation before submission of my very complex form. The whole thing needs to be understood by Angular, and the custom validation messages need to display consistently between fields.)

Comment: I see. I would say I wouldn't trust comparing dates as strings, and you might want to find a way to compare them as UNIX timestamps. (either using your own validation model, or adding a hidden field that shows date as UNIX time and compares the dates as integers)

Comment: Again, this is just the Angular API. Angular, ostensibly, is parsing the strings for the min/max to real date objects, and performing the comparisons on that basis. But Angular specifies strings...